# Applying Linux rt patch

Tags: linux-kernel, patch

I'm trying to apply the rt-patch to the standard kernel from kernel.org.  So far I have tried 3.14 and 3.10 from here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/ with the corresponding kernel version.

My problem is that when I come to patch the kernel, I get the following type of output that I do not understand:

> |There's some hardware latency that takes 2 microseconds to run. |
>   |Signed-off-by: Steven Rostedt  |Signed-off-by:
>   Sebastian Andrzej Siewior  |--- |
>   drivers/misc/hwlat_detector.c |   32 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++------
>   | 1 file changed, 26 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-) | |---
>   a/drivers/misc/hwlat_detector.c |+++ b/drivers/misc/hwlat_detector.c
>   -------------------------- File to patch:

This is from command:

> bzcat ../patches-3.10.10-rt7.tar.bz2 | patch -p1 --dry-run

What is it asking me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

patches-3.10.10-rt7.tar.bz2 is a tar file containing a lot of patches as individual files.  You can't just feed that to the patch command and have it do the right thing.

If you get the patch-3.10.10-rt7.patch.bz2 file it should work using the command you've shown.